# undefined symbol SQLAllocHandle using perl on Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, perl, ubuntu, unixodbc

It seems like the perl program is trying to load the ODBC.so file instead of the freetds file that should be used instead.  It's giving a symbol lookup error message.  Trying to find SQLAllocHandle in ODBC.so

Has anyone ran into this error before?  Just got done installing the drivers so I'm completely at a loss and utterly confused.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue.  iodbc drivers were affecting the unixodbc drivers.  So I removed the iodbc files from /usr/lib.

Removed the DBD::ODBC module and then reinstalled it.

Fixed.

Comment: You can avoid this my running Makefile.PL with the -x argument. It is unfortunate but the Makefile.PL looks for iODBC before unixODBC (long story).